# JackSon ObjectMapper conversion Issues

Tags: jackson

I am new to using `org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper` and while doing something, landed into certain issues that I wanted to run by experts.

I am using `org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper` to convert my java objects to a JSON Object and then finally pass that to my views for further usage. I am using Spring Wiring for doing this all and here is what I face -

1. While conversion, it converts all my float or double (basically decimal) values to integer. Is there a way I can stop it from happening, by simply disabling or enabling a feature in my `ObjectMapper` class wiring or in some other way.
2. I also noticed that the Object that I am converting (has got another objects inside it) is losing the order of elements inside a collection. So say I have an Object that has another Collection of Objects as an instance  variable, and that inner object has got the order of elements in "XYZ, when it gets converted it loses this order and comes up with it's own.

How to preserve the exact same order that I had in my Java Object before it as sent to conversion?

1. Some of the methods in my Object (the one I am converting) has return boolean values and have some logic inside, and some of the times because of the data differences, it ends up getting `Null Pointer exception` while the conversion. I know I should check for nulls before conversion, but is there a way for Jackson mapper to ignore all these null objects that it encounters during the conversion.